# Accessing XML node with variable instead of integer in the code - why won't it use a variable?

Tags: php, arrays, xml, variables

The short story is

This works :  `$xml->person[2]->fullname = $name;`

but This DOES NOT :   `$id = $_POST['id'];  $xml->person[$id]->fullname=$name;`

I need to use the $id variable since it's being passed from a previous page through an html form.  However I'm not sure why it won't work no matter what I do until I put in the actual integer instead of the variable.  What's wrong with my code and why won't this work?  I've also noticed that this same code (with the variable) works in another file but not this one - what's the deal with using variables here?

Here are some of the errors :

> Notice: Indirect modification of overloaded element of SimpleXMLElement has no effect in edit.php on line 15
>
> Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /edit.php on line 15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a slight difference between

```
$xml->person[2]->fullname;
```

and

```
$id = $_POST['id'];  
$xml->person[$id]->fullname;
```

And the difference is, in the first example 2 is a number (integer) and in the second, `$id` is a string.

Strings in **SimpleXMLElement** [**ArrayAccess**](https://php.net/arrayaccess) (these `[...]` brackets) denote an attribute node with the name of the string. As the attribute named as given from `$id` does not exists, it is created *on-the-fly* but not yet part of the document. Therefore it can't be modified (operating with `->` on it for example).

Equipped with this knowledge, casting the string to an integer should put the burden away:

```
$id = (int) $_POST['id'];  
$xml->person[$id]->fullname;
```

Cheers. Example:

```
<?php
/**
 * Accessing XML node with variable instead of integer in the code - why won't it use a variable?
 *
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/q/29285579/367456
 */

$buffer = <<<XML
<doc>
    <person><fullname>Sally Stewart</fullname></person>
    <person><fullname>Nicole Kidman</fullname></person>
</doc>
XML;

$xml = simplexml_load_string($buffer);

$name = 'Gregory Peck';

$id = (int) '2';

$xml->person[$id]->fullname = $name;

$xml->asXML('php://output');
```

Output (beautified):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <person><fullname>Sally Stewart</fullname></person>
    <person><fullname>Nicole Kidman</fullname></person>
    <person><fullname>Gregory Peck</fullname></person>
</doc>
```

Comment: Thank you for the very clear answer and example.  Sure enough, that fixed my problems for me!